# What does the clock symbol mean in Metamask

Tags: blockchain, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I just want to ask what the clock symbol means in Metamask?

[image: Metamask wallet symbol]

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's an L-symbol, not a clock? :-)

Comment: Yes true, then maybe "Live"?

Answer (score 0):

That's the icon where the account is connected.

For example when connected to uniswap it will show the unicorn icon.

[image]